# ReacJs and fetch json and update state prop

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack

I'm a bit disappointed of my results about getting started with reactjs.

I'm now just trying to parse json data from a simple restful ws.

If I put on chrome the url of rest get query, it answers correctly a json array:

```
[{"label":"TestLabel!!","value":7,"rating":17.25},{"label":"TestLabel2 !!","value":8,"rating":18.25}]
```

this is my React component:

```
export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { items: [{"label":"Test1!!","value":7,"rating":17.25}] };
    } 

     componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/rest/json/product/get') 
            .then(result=> { 
                this.state.items.push(result); 
            });
    }

    render() {
      return(
                <div>
                    <div>Items:</div>
                    {
                        this.state.items.map(function(item, i){
                           return <div key={i}>{item.label}</div> 
                        }
                    )}          
                </div>  
            );
    }
}
```

This, after lots of tweaking, shows no errors, but nothing happens to the list, which shows only the constructor element.

Pls point me to the right direction...

thanks

SOLVED:

the "setState()" as suggested was part of the problem.
The other part is the way i manage the json answer.

This way the project works:

```
 componentDidMount() {
     fetch('/rest/json/product/get') 
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {  
          this.setState({items:  response });
        })
 }
```

But I just tried another way to implement the call by chance since i was totally lost. 
I feel a bit confused. What is the correct way to implement a fetch?

Anyways...this is ok.

Comment: Check if the response has the correct content type, I would expect that if not specified you would get text/plain instead of javascript/application or whatever it's the current convention

Comment: have you tried `this.setState` instead of `this.state.items.push(result);`? plus i dont think doing it in `componentDidMount` is such a good idea

Comment: you are trying to push array as another object to array...

Comment: try `this.setState('items',result)`

Comment: this way I got 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function'. The json is the problem? but the output is a proper json array.

Comment: Nice that you found a solution, but would you mind posting your **solution** as an **answer** (and accept that 3 days later as correct), rather than editing it into the **question**, because - well, a solution is no question. It helps to have an accepted answer, so other people with a similar question will see imediately that this question *has an answer*, before reading the whole thing. If you have another question, don't chain it to this one, but **ask a new question instead**

Comment: I solved but didn't understand WHY I oughted to pass 2 times the response since it was ALREADY a json, and I'm afraid that couldn't be the BEST approach. I think that merely solving without knowing what's going on exactly ins't the real goal of Stackoverlow's community.

Answer (score 1):

Read the last line in the [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#props):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

try this:
`this.setState((state) => ({ items: state.items.concat(result) }))`

or you can do this if result is array:
`this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items , ...result] })`

Answer (score 0):

try `this.setState('items',result)`

Comment: This should work but gaves me "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function". If I put the real json array in place of result, that works. So my json isn't properly transmitted? But is the same thing I've pasted inside result...

Comment: it can be simple typo, have you tried to pass it through some JSOn validator?